# How to edit default portlet in Liferay 7 Control Panel?

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

Is it possible to edit portlet/page in Control Panel in Liferay 7.0 ga4? 
In my case, I want to add a custom column in Users table in 'Users and Organizations' section.

[image: Users and organizations - control panel]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, and you do so just like you'd do for any other stock portlet. While there are extra mechanics to make them appear in control panel, you don't need to get in contact with these if you just modify.

Inspect the Dom to get a hint for the portlet that you're looking for.

An alternative that'd be better maintainable would be to write your own portlet instead of modifying an existing one. But that's not what you ask for here.

Comment: but do i have to modify liferay source and compile it from source code?

Comment: No, you don't need to recompile. What you need to do depends on the level of modification or maintainability that you're looking for. Customizing stock portlets is well documented and a general instruction would be out off scope here. Look it up and come back with concrete questions if the documentation leaves them open.

Comment: Thanks for yours advices, I finally managed how to achieve this, I couldn't find where concretely the code of JSPs to edit is. I've used Liferay Module Project Fragment from Liferay IDE.